# How to drop duplicates based on value in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a very simple Pandas dataframe:

```
Revenue     City
27          "New York"
59          "New York"
52          "New York"
34          "London"
14          "London"
24          "London"
45          "Tokyo"
54          "Los Angeles"
24          "Los Angeles"
```

I would like to remove all duplicates in 'City' column, **except** if the city name **is not** in the following list : `["Los Angeles", "New York"]. The expected output is :

```
Revenue     City
27          "New York"
34          "London"
14          "London"
24          "London"
45          "Tokyo"
54          "Los Angeles"
```

So far I found this, but I don't think it solves the same problem as mine and it doesn't work anyway :

```
mask = ["Los Angeles", "New York"]
df = df.loc[(df['City'].duplicated(keep=False) == False) | (~df['City'].isin(mask)]
```

Comment: so you want to keep one entry if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df = df.loc[(df.duplicated(subset=['City'], keep='first') == False) | (~df['City'].isin(mask)]
```